# How to fix invalid use of incomplete type when create a child class from Gtk::Menu?

Tags: c++, fedora, gtkmm4

when trying to create a custom menu class that is inherited from `Gtk::Menu` the following output containing `invalid use of incomplete type` is thrown

```
main.cc:5:28: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Gtk::Menu’
    5 | class AppMenu: public Gtk::Menu
      |                            ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/gtkmm-4.0/gtkmm.h:207,
                 from main.cc:1:
/usr/include/gtkmm-4.0/gtkmm/label.h:46:17: note: forward declaration of ‘class Gtk::Menu’
   46 | class GTKMM_API Menu;
      |
```

main.cc

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
//#include <gtkmm/menu.h>

class AppMenu: public Gtk::Menu
{
    public:
        AppMenu();
};

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling using the command

```
g++ main.cc 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-4.0' -I/usr/include/gtkmm-4.0/gtkmm/menu.h
```

I tried using the header `<gtkmm/menu.h>` but this is not found for whatever reason, also i tried to use `class Gtk::Menu;` but this is wrong since the class is already declared in gtkmm header file

Comment: You just *have to* include the header that defines `Menu`. No way around that. A forward declaration `class Menu;` allows you to use a pointer or reference to the class, but not much else. As a base class, its members must be known.

Comment: @BoP i did try to use `#include <gtkmm/menu.h>` but the header is not found

Comment: So that is not the correct include path. Either it is missing from the install, or it is somewhere else - at a different path. Up to you to find out.

Comment: @BoP I did add `-I-I/usr/include/gtkmm-4.0/gtkmm/menu.h` to the compile command but still the same error

Comment: @misha, add only `-I/usr/include/gtkmm-4.0` and retry.

Comment: `gtkmm-4` doesn't have `menu.h`, you need to go to the giomm library for that. Also, gtkmm classes are not really designed for inheritance.

Comment: @n.m. i am using pkg-config and it automatically adds giomm but i still get the incomplete type error

Comment: You need to `#include <giomm/menu.h>`.